# Why does reverse depth buffering provide more precision? (with DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT Datatype layout)

Tags: directx, optimization, depth-buffer, pipeline

I lately came around methods optimizing the use of the depth buffer, as the easiest solution reverse depth buffering is mentioned but I cannot wrap my head around why I would be gaining a better depth distribution with it.

First I thought it to be that way because floats use well floating point format so if I can map 90% of the scene to near zero i can benefit from floats great precision near zero but then I saw that those 8 bit for the exponent are being reserved by stencil so now I don't think they store exponent data?

Edit: Now that i was told unnorm are just fixed precision and have actually tested that it does improve depth resolution indeed I dont understand how it can improve Z-buffering without having exponent data has someone a theory regarding why? If the UNORMs have fixed precision it should´nt matter whether I map the 99% that don't lay 3 meters in front of the camera to one or to zero.

Comment: depth as written to the depth buffer is not linear

Comment: Well thats clear and part of the problem I know that, but reversing far and nearplane does nothing more than mirroring the depth values along 0.5 so if UNORM floats don´t have exponent bits this will yield as few values for distant parts of the scene as before or am I mistaken?

Comment: [UNORM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is not a floating point value, its fixed point masked in an int

Comment: Yes thats what I feared, so then there is actually no gain at all in reverse depth buffering using them? So I have to drop the stencils and change the format to a real float to benefit from reverse depth buffering?

Comment: yes, [DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173059%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a 32 bit floating point depth buffer

Comment: [This](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/depth-precision-visualized) article on that topic should make things clearer

Comment: Thank you for the link I already read that article before, I know the logic behind it but I question whether this can possibly work when having stencils activated because like you said the datatype becomes fixed point when I use this format and I dont think this will still have benefits then.

If so, is there possibly a way to have stencils and 32 bit floating point depth values at the same time?

Comment: Ok I found DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT_S8X24_UINT which should improve things by having exponents but does´nt quite, maybe it isnt supported for my 7 year old laptop...